# Common Lisp: Why does this function cause infinite recursion?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, infinite-loop

I am trying to write a function (lnn; list-not-nil) similar to list that only appends values that are not nil.

```
(list nil 3) --> (NIL 3)
(lnn nil 3) --> (3)
```

Here is the code I have so far. For some reason it causes infinite recursion on any input that I try.

```
(defun lnn (&rest items)
  (lnn-helper nil items))

(defun lnn-helper (so-far items)
   (cond ((null items)
           so-far)
     ((null (car items))
      (lnn-helper so-far (cdr items)))
     (t (lnn-helper (append so-far (list (car items))) (cdr items)))))
```

Any ideas? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun lnn-helper (so-far &rest items)
  ...)
```

With this argument list, `items` will never be `nil` if you always call `lnn-helper` with two arguments.  Remove the `&rest` specifier, and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you, I made this correction, but I still get infinite recursion.

Comment: @Miriam It works for me: `(lnn nil 3)` => `(3)`; `(lnn 1 2 nil 3)` =>
`(1 2 3)`.  What input results in the infinite recursion?

Comment: I'd also be tempted to CONS the elements onto the head of SO-FAR, then finish by returning (NREVERSE SO-FAR), won't matter for short lists, but APPEND is O(n) so LNN-HELPER ends up being O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

Matthias' answer should have helped. Also note, that this is just a simple reduction:

```
(defun lnn (&rest elements)
  (reduce (lambda (elt acc) (if elt (cons elt acc) acc))
          elements
          :from-end t
          :initial-value nil))
```

Or even (less efficient):

```
(defun lnn (&rest elements)
  (reduce #'cons (remove nil elements) :from-end t :initial-value nil))
```

Then:

```
(defun lnn (&rest elements)
  (remove nil elements))
```

:)

P.S.: I know this was probably just an exercise in recursion, but SCNR.